# Validar si la fecha es 2 o más meses anterior a la fecha actual - PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Tengo este problema, en el cual debo saber si las siguientes fechas son de 2 meses o más anteriores a la fecha actual.

Para eso he creado el siguiente arreglo, en donde detallo el resultado esperado:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2021-06-01" -> true
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2021-07-01" -> true
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2021-08-01" -> false
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2021-09-01" -> false
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2021-10-01" -> false
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2022-05-01" -> false
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2022-08-01" -> false
}
```

Anteriormente había solicitado ayuda con buscar la diferencia de 2 meses, pero el planteamiento fue erróneo, solo busqué la diferencia de 2 meses, y no la diferencia de 2 meses solo hacia "atrás".

Por lo que tengo esto como prueba:

```
$fechas = ["2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-10-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-08-01"];
$hoy = new DateTime();
echo $hoy->format("Y-m") . "</br>";
foreach ($fechas as $f) {
    $fecha = new DateTime($f);
    if ($hoy->diff($fecha)->m > 2) {
        echo $fecha->format("Y-m") . " +2 meses de diferencia</br>";
    } else {
        echo $fecha->format("Y-m") . " Menor o Igual a 2 meses de diferencia </br>";
    }
}
```

Actualmente, este código deja afuera los últimos 2 registros que son fechas futuras, las cuales deberían ser false, pero las manda como true.

Answer (score 0):

Me calenté la cabeza para nada, debí haber empezado por obtener la fecha actual -2 meses desde el inicio...

```
$hoy = new DateTime();
$comparar = $hoy->modify("-2 months");

foreach ($fechas as $f) {
    $fecha = new DateTime($f);
    if ($fecha->format("Y-m") < $comparar->format("Y-m")) {
        echo $fecha->format("Y-m") . " +2 meses de diferencia</br>";
    } else {
        echo $fecha->format("Y-m") . " -2 meses de diferencia o futura </br>";
    }
}
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres lograr. Según esto, la fecha `2021-06-01` sería `+2 meses de diferencia` con respecto a la fecha de hoy, lo cual no es cierto. Esa fecha es `-2 meses de diferencia`. ¿El error es sólo en el mensaje de tu código o está a otro nivel? La verdad es que el planteamiento de la pregunta es un poco confuso. Además, creo que convendría usar intervalos para esto.

Comment: @A.Cedano https://i.gyazo.com/8ba219482b9410e226c86666e71c2cbd.png

Comment: Espera, como es que el 6 seria -2 meses, si estamos a 10 ??? 10 - 6 = 4 no ??

Comment: Sí, perdona, me confundí. Hay más de dos meses de diferencia entre la fecha de hoy y `2021-06-01` .

Comment: Quiero advertir simplemente que trabajar con fechas modificadas no es seguro. Haz esta prueba y verás a qué me refiero: `$hoy = new DateTime("2021-08-31");
$comparar = $hoy->modify("-2 months"); var_dump($comparar);` Ahí la fecha que obtendrás será `2021-07-01`, eso podría ser problemático en algún caso. Ya eso depende de lo que signifique *mes* en tu contexto. Si *dos meses antes* aquí significaría el **30 de junio** el código será erróneo en casos como estos.